# Posting div/text when box checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm relatively new to JS and was looking for an article or method in which to accomplish the following - be it a form or just JS. (Would like to avoid PHP.)

I have a series of check boxes call them box 1 - 4, which when any  one is checked should either show a div or post text to a particular div on the page.

Example: when box 1 is checked div A posts "Box one has been checked."

I'm not certain how to refine my searches to find an example of what I'm looking for but did find a jsfiddle with a similar technique this posts a textbox under the checkbox when activated.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7gdX/2/)

```
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" value="results" />Results
<div id="formContainer"></div>

var textboxId = 0;

function CreateTextbox() {
    var textBox = document.createElement("input");
    textBox.setAttribute("type", "textbox");
    textBox.setAttribute("id", textboxId);
    textboxId++;
    return textBox;
}

document.getElementById("chk").onclick = function () {
    if (textboxId == 0) {
         document.getElementById("formContainer").appendChild(CreateTextbox(textboxId));
        textboxId = 1;
    } else if (textboxId == 1) {
        document.getElementById("formContainer").innerHTML = '';
        textboxId = 0;
        //The code to remove the previosuly made textbox
    }
}
```

Any direction or code ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In your demo given you have only one `checkbox` which creates/destroys a `textbox` on click. Can you please elaborate in a detailed way how you want it?

Comment: My goal is to create a textbox/div with pre written data. When check box 1 is click, pre written text appears or becomes visible in a certain div.

Comment: using `jquery` is fine? or pure `javascript`?

Comment: jquery would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you are expecting.

```js
$('.chkbox').on('click',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')) //check if checkbox is checked or unchecked
   {
       $(this).next('.formContainer').html('<div class="new">'+$(this).data('detail')+'</div>'); 
       //get detail to add from the clicked checkbox's data-* attribute
   }
   else
   {
       $(this).next('.formContainer').html('');
       //just empty the html below it
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="chk" data-detail="Box one has been checked." class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />Results
<div class="formContainer"></div>
<input id="chk2" data-detail="Box two has been checked." class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />Results
<div class="formContainer"></div>
<input id="chk3" data-detail="Box three has been checked." class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />Results
<div class="formContainer"></div>
<input id="chk4" data-detail="Box four has been checked." class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />Results
<div class="formContainer"></div>
```

> **Add detail for each `checkbox` in its `data-detail` property. Refer html above**

**[Extenal Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/v7gdX/31/)**

---

**Update**

To display all the text in a single `div` you can just refer the target element as below:

```
$('.chkbox').on('click',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
       $('.formContainer').html('<div class="new">'+$(this).data('detail')+'</div>'); //directly refer the element
   }
   else
   {
       $('.formContainer').html('');
   }
});
```

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/v7gdX/33/)**

Comment: Very very close, thank you! Is there anyway for the posted data to the be congregated into one separated div rather than under the check boxes?

Comment: @BR89 Check the updated answer.. If you want to append the message rather than removing it each time on click of `checkbox` then there is a different process.. let me know if that is what you want..

Comment: I should be able to modify this the rest of the way to the specifics. You've been a massive help. I sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: dude you were the first person helped on  y first question... 1upvote for you only ......

Comment: @Rush.2707.. My pleasure to help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you really need, but this should help you get started, It also requires jquery

HTML

```
<input class="mychk" type="checkbox" value="Box 1 is Check" />Box 1<br>
<input class="mychk" type="checkbox" value="Box 2 Box is Check" />Box 2<br>
<input class="mychk" type="checkbox" value="Box 3 Box is Check" />Box 3<br>
<input class="mychk" type="checkbox" value="Box 4 Box is Check" />Box 4
<div class="showcheck">I'll Be Overwritten When Checkbox is check</div>
```

jQuery

```
(function($) {

    //run for each input box
    $('.mychk').each( function() {

        // detect change action
        $(this).change( function() {

            // if the checkbox is check
            if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                //insert checkbox value in showcontent div
                $('.showcheck').html( $(this).val() );
            } else {
                // if uncheck, assign default value
                $('.showcheck').html( 'Default Content' );
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ua69pd1/)

Comment: Silver, thanks for this! If I add a seperate function for each check box, will that make it so the posted text isn't replaced (allowing multiple "Box # is checked" to be posted?

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript answer:

HTML:

```
<div id="checkboxes">

    <input id="one" type="checkbox"></input>
    <input id="two" type="checkbox"></input>
    <input id="three" type="checkbox"></input>

</div>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

JS:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementById("checkboxes").children, function(element) {
    element.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = element.id + " " + element.checked;
    }
});
```

[JSfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7gdX/30/)